# After moved Magento, special price / date doesn't work like it should

Tags: magento-1.9, special-price

After moving my web shop from one hosting to another, the special price / dates doesn't seem to work correctly anymore.

If I set the special price to be from today to next week, it will only show for example today and stop the next day.

I echo:ed out the time with datetime() and the time was correct, only two hours behind, which shouldn't cause more troubles.

I have not changed the code after the moving of the web shop, so I do have a hard time figure out what it could be.

Any suggestion in fail searching here / Finding out what's causing the problem, because to me... it seems very weird.

Comment: please check server time zone & magento time zone setting

Comment: As I wrote in the post, server time goes 2 hours behind, and time zone is correct. echo datetime(); shows correct date. So the problem still remains; why would the special price end after one day?